# Try to update SQL table With Java JDBC get error "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to update a SQL table using Java JDBC with the following query
`UPDATE PLAYER SET FIRST_NAME ='king', LAST_NAME ='guy', ADDRESS ='', PROVINCE ='', POSTAL_CODE ='', PHONE_NUMBER ='' WHERE PLAYER_ID=7;`

But I get the error message

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

This is my java code

```
String update= updatetf.getText();
String fname = fnametf.getText();
String lname = lnametf.getText();
String addr = addresstf.getText();
String province = provincetf.getText();
String pcode= pcodetf.getText();
String phone= phonetf.getText();

        try {
            Statement stm = connection.createStatement();

            String sql = "UPDATE PLAYER SET "+
                    "FIRST_NAME ='"+ fname + "', "
                    +"LAST_NAME ='" + lname + "', "
                    +"ADDRESS ='" + addr + "', "
                    +"PROVINCE ='" + province + "', "
                    +"POSTAL_CODE ='" + pcode + "', "
                    +"PHONE_NUMBER ='" + phone + "'"
                    + " WHERE PLAYER_ID=" + update+";";

            System.out.println(sql);
            stm.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Player " + update + " updated.");
        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }`
```

The above code forms the following query

`UPDATE PLAYER SET FIRST_NAME ='king', LAST_NAME ='guy', ADDRESS ='', PROVINCE ='', POSTAL_CODE ='', PHONE_NUMBER ='' WHERE PLAYER_ID=7;`

But I get the error message

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I tried the query in SQL developer and didn't get any error

Answer (score 5):

The error could actually be caused by the semicolon at the end of the SQL statement, which should not be needed there anyway.  But in any case, you really should he using a prepared statement here.  Consider using this version:

```java
String sql = "UPDATE PLAYER SET " +
             "FIRST_NAME = ?, "   +
             "LAST_NAME = ?, "    +
             "ADDRESS = ?, "      +
             "PROVINCE = ?, "     +
             "POSTAL_CODE = ?, "  +
             "PHONE_NUMBER = ? "  +
             "WHERE PLAYER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = new PreparedStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, fname);
ps.setString(2, lname);
ps.setString(3, addr);
ps.setString(4, province);
ps.setString(5, pcode);
ps.setString(6, phone);
ps.setInteger(7, update);

int rows = ps.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("num rows updated: " + rows);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason of adding semicolon is causing exception? Should sql command not be ended with semicolon? I also have noticed this error in spring while dealing with native sql. But don't know the proper reason. If you know the reason it would be a great help.

Comment: Because there's a translation layer at work. When you're sending commands via e.g. the psql command line app or whatnot, semicolon tells that app: "Ok, go run this". By _not_ typing it you can press enter and keep typing, in case you want to multi-line your SQL statement. In java, if you want to run 2 statements, you have to make 2 actual statement objects and run those. The `;` is for the benefit of the command line tool or SQL 'command utility', whatever it may be. It's not actually part of the SQL statement _itself_. Java just sends it along, and you get this error.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Good explanation, and I'll add that depending on the database and JDBC driver, leaving the trailing semicolon there _might_ work, but AFAIK it's never necessary, and so it is probably better to omit it.

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot and Tim Biegeleisen for your nice explanation.